# How to find array item inside another array item in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make a wishlist where I use localstorage. When clicked on "add to wishlist" button the item is added to localstorage and then shows "remove from wishlist" button. I was trying to computed using *filter* and *find* ES6 but I might got it wrong. Here is my [codesandbox-link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wishlist-ouuyw?file=/src/App.vue) and also below is the code. Please someone help thanks.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wishlist-ouuyw?file=/src/App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <h2>Total Selected: {{selectedEntries.length}}</h2>
    <div v-for="entry in entries" :key="entry.id">
      <div class="content-wrap">
      
        <h3>{{entry.title}}</h3>
        <button v-if="!checkExists" @click="addToWishlist(entry.id)">Add Wishlist</button>
        <button v-else @click="removeToWishlist(entry.id)">Remove Wishlist</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  data(){
    return{
      entries: [
        {
          title: 'entry one',
          id: 1
        },
        {
          title: 'entry two',
          id: 2
        },
        {
          title: 'entry three',
          id: 3
        },
        {
          title: 'entry four',
          id: 4
        },
        {
          title: 'entry five',
          id: 5
        },
      ],
      selectedEntries: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("wishlistItems")) || []
    }
  },
  computed:{
    checkExists(){
      return this.entries.filter(entryItem => {
         this.selectedEntries.find(selectedId => {
           return entryItem.id === selectedId.id
         })
      })
    }
  },
  methods:{
    addToWishlist(entryId){
      this.selectedEntries.push({ id: entryId });
      window.localStorage.setItem("wishlistItems", JSON.stringify(this.selectedEntries));
      console.log("Clicked>>>", this.selectedEntries)
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.content-wrap{
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}
.content-wrap h3{
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 30%;
}
.content-wrap button{
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #1d9a61;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: .7
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method which checks if the object is present in the selected objects array and shows the respective buttons accordingly. I'm not sure why you only wish to keep it as a `computed` property. Because computed properties are not really used for computing values of array elements on the fly. `Computed` property methods don't take in an argument, so its not directly possible. Computed properties are used more for single values defined in the `data` property. Look at their [official documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#basic-example).

So if you want to go with a `computed` property only, then you will have to create a `computed` property for fetching the `matching` items and then create another method that basically takes in this matching items array and the current `entry.id` and returns a boolean. But this is not a good solution. Ideal solution would be to just have it as a method that takes the current `entry.id` as an argument as shown below.

.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <h2>Total Selected: {{selectedEntries.length}}</h2>
    <div v-for="entry in entries" :key="entry.id">
      <div class="content-wrap">
      
        <h3>{{entry.title}}</h3>
        <button v-if="!checkExists(entry.id)" @click="addToWishlist(entry.id)">Add Wishlist</button>
        <button v-else @click="removeToWishlist(entry.id)">Remove Wishlist</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  data(){
    return{
      entries: [
        {
          title: 'entry one',
          id: 1
        },
        {
          title: 'entry two',
          id: 2
        },
        {
          title: 'entry three',
          id: 3
        },
        {
          title: 'entry four',
          id: 4
        },
        {
          title: 'entry five',
          id: 5
        },
      ],
      // selectedEntries: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("wishlistItems")) || [],
      selectedEntries: [{
          title: 'entry one',
          id: 1
        },
        {
          title: 'entry two',
          id: 2
        }],
    }
  },
  methods:{
    addToWishlist(entryId){
      this.selectedEntries.push({ id: entryId });
      window.localStorage.setItem("wishlistItems", JSON.stringify(this.selectedEntries));
      console.log("Clicked>>>", this.selectedEntries)
    },

    checkExists(entryId){
      return this.selectedEntries.find(item => item.id === entryId);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.content-wrap{
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}
.content-wrap h3{
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 30%;
}
.content-wrap button{
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #1d9a61;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: .7
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm very thankful to you. That's great. I understand fully and your explanation is awesome. Thanks a lot

Comment: @JoneySpark appreciate the kind words.. Thanks!